# Python - How to make line by line replacements using values from an array

Tags: python, for-loop, xml-parsing

I currently have a Python script that parses a file (in this case an XML file) and makes line by line replacements as necessary, depending on the values of multiple arrays. As it stands now the script works great, but feel like it could be a lot better. I'll also need to add few more arrays later on and am worried about performance.

Additionally, the way I currently have it set up doesn't allow for counting and printing the total replacements that have been made. (e.g. "Replaced: xyz -- Made XX replacements") While not an immediate requirement, I'd like to add this functionality in the future.

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions!

Here's the code:

```
arrayOne = ["old string one", "new string one"]
arrayTwo = ["old string two", "new string two"]

# Variable 'path' collected from command line input
f = open(path, "r", encoding="utf8")
newFile = open(path.replace(".xml", "-new.xml"), "w", encoding="utf8")

def replace(a,b):
    for data in f:
        for datatype in (arrayOne, arrayTwo):
            data = data.replace(datatype[a], datatype[b])
        newFile.write(data)
    newFile.close()

replace(0,1)

f.close()
```

Comment: I think this is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks -- I've cross-posted it to codereview per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think it looks reasonably efficient, although a little confusing. I'd say try it with a bunch of arrays and see if performance is an issue. It might become messy if you have a huge amount of arrays and have to list them all like you do now. Personally I think I'd put them all in a big dictionary, with "old strings" being the keys. This is what I did below.

As for your print line at the end, I think that would be easy enough through a counter, as shown below.

Also, as it sits now I don't think you need `replace` to be a separate function, unless you're planning on making it do something more complicated.

```
myDictionary = {'old string one' : 'new string one',
                'old string two' : 'new string two'}

# Variable 'path' collected from command line input
f = open(path, "r", encoding="utf8")
newFile = open(path.replace(".xml", "-new.xml"), "w", encoding="utf8")
counter = 0

for data in f:
    for key in myDictionary:
        if key in data:
            data = data.replace(key, myDictionary[key])
            counter += 1
    newFile.write(data)
newFile.close()

f.close()

print 'Replaced', path, 'Made', counter, 'replacements.'
```